# android apk + proguard : -adaptresourcefilecontents doesn't do anything

Tags: android, proguard

I've got some resources in my android app that need to have class names in a resource file rewritten to match the new obfuscated class name.

Theoretically that's what -adaptresourcefilecontents is for. However when used in an android build, it doesn't seem to work and the resource in the apk is the original ones.

I've tried both gradle and maven and got the same result

Gradle test project: https://github.com/ymenager/sandbox/tree/master/DelemeApp

Maven test project: https://github.com/ymenager/sandbox/tree/master/morseflash

Anyone knows how to get it to work ???

Answer (score 0):

It's like that by design/default, and the developers have declined making changes in order to allow resource obsfuction to work on maven/android projects (see github issue simpligility/android-maven-plugin#667)